# how to fill in the asp page and invoke submit button and view the result page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am newbies of webclient process. 
This is the asp page that I want to login from my web application:-

```
http://localhost/alis/services.asp

<TABLE width="1261">
  <FORM action="sign_handler_control_id.asp" onsubmit="return LoginForm_Validation(this)" name="TheForm" method="post" >

  <TBODY>
   <TR>
  <TH width="700" valign="middle" align="left"><FONT color="#000000"><U><FONT color="#000000" face="Arial" size="+1">Pengguna yang telah mendaftar, sila masukkan Kod Agensi, ID Pengguna dan Katalaluan</FONT></U><FONT color="#000000" face="Georgia" size="-1">.</FONT></FONT><FONT size="+1" color="#000000"><U><FONT face=Tahoma 
size=-1 color="#000000"><BR>
  </FONT></U></FONT><FONT size="+1"><FONT face="Tahoma" size="-1"><BR>
    <BR>
     </FONT></FONT>
    <TABLE width="1261" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" height="56" style="height: 31px; left: 10px; top: 326px">
   <TBODY>
      <TR>
        <TD width="126"><FONT face="Arial" size="+0"><B>Kod Agensi</B></FONT></TD>
        <TD width="300" colspan="2">
        <INPUT size="3" tabindex="1" type="text" name="agcy_id"  maxlength="3" onFocus="nextfield='agcy_id1';">&nbsp;
        <INPUT size="5" tabindex="1" type="text" name="agcy_id1"  maxlength="5" onblur="jump(this)" onFocus="nextfield='user_id';">&nbsp;
        </TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD width="126"></TD>
       <TD width="300" colspan="2"><INPUT size="95" tabindex="1" type="text" name="agcy_desc" maxlength="150" onblur="fc()" disabled></TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD width="126"><FONT face="Arial" size="+0"><B>ID Pengguna</B></FONT></TD>
        <TD width="300" colspan="2"><INPUT size="20" type="text" name="user_id" tabindex="2" maxlength="8" onFocus="nextfield='new_pwd';"></TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD width="126"><FONT face="Arial" size="+0"><B>Katalaluan</B></FONT></TD>
        <TD width="300" colspan="2">
        <INPUT size="20" type="password" name="new_pwd" tabindex="3" maxlength="8" onFocus="nextfield='SubmitLogin';">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<script src="accept.asp"><INPUT size="1" type="hidden" name="acceptvalue" value="1"></script>
        </TD>
      </TR>
    </TBODY>

  <td width="126">

  <BR>

  <td width="300" colspan="2">

  <TR>
  <TD width="126">
    <p align="left"></TD>

  <TD width="145">
    <p align="right"><INPUT type="submit"  id="SubmitLogin" name="SubmitLogin" value="Login" tabindex="4"></TD>
```

There is 5 fields that I need to fill in and invoke the Login button. 
1. agcy_id
2. agcy_id1
3. agcy_desc
4. user_id
5. new_pwd

How can I automatically login using asp.net C#?Anyone have any idea how can I start it? Appreciate for your reply.

Comment: what do you mean when you want automatic login. Filling all the field and the submit will automatically login?

Comment: Yes.I want to login by programmatically using C# asp.net.

Comment: still, do you want AFTER filling all the field of by coockie?

Comment: I want to view the result page after login. I have all the data to login but how to write code to login that page?

Comment: Use asp.net button control and create a method buttonclick method for the button and find the each control values and connect to db. You can find the controls using jquery or with java script.

Comment: Roddam Ramesh :: how to find the controls using jquery or with java script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a `POST` request using Jquery - ajax passing your form data parameters
for example:

```
var formData = {agcy_id :"val",agcy_id1 :"val2",agcy_desc :"val3", agcy_desc:"val4"}; 

$.ajax({
    url : "YOUR_POST_URL",
    type: "POST",
    data : formData,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        //data - response from server
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {

    }
});
```

Here you have live examples of AJAX calls, and answers from servers receiving parameters:

[Jquery AJAX POST Example](http://hayageek.com/examples/jquery/ajax-post/index.php)

Once you performed tha AJAX POST you can retrieve the parameters inside codebehind:

```
NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
string agcy_id_var;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["agcy_id "]))
{
  agcy_id_var= nvc["agcy_id "];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am sorry I cannot understand. I never use ajax before. what is textStatus and jqXHR

Comment: I added a link with live example. It is a client side code you will allow you to call a form. I guess you want to call an ASPX page, and it will receive all the parameters from html.

Comment: You just include a <script type="text/javascript"> with the ajax call inside and put the jquery source in head declaration